# How to allow input field to be modified in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a normal input field, that allows typing by the user, as well as being "autocompleted" with some data from it's parent.

```
class SimpleForm extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            form_name: "",
            price: ""
        }
    }


    render()
    {
        return (
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input value={this.state.form_name} onChange={(e) => { this.setState({form_name: e.target.value}) }}/>
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

class ParentOfForm extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return (
            <SimpleForm howDoIsendToInputField="garbage" />


        )

    }

}
```

If I use defaultValue in the input field, I can't change it later on. If I set `<input value={this.props.something}>`, I can't modify the input field...

Comment: you can use `this.props.something || this.state.form_name`

Comment: Use "defaultValue" instead of "value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initializing `ParentOfForm` with prop `howDoIsendToInputField` = `garbage`. So you might rewrite your constructor of `SimpleForm` to use the prop from the parent form as initial state value:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    form_name: props.howDoIsendToInputField,
  };
}
```

That way you have pre-filled the input field with your prop value. In the React lingo your input field is controlled now, since you provide a specific value.

The react docs just added a new section that illustrates this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs

What you can do to reflect changes in the prop is to use `componentWillReceiveProps` within your `SimpleForm` component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({ form_name: nextProps.howDoIsendToInputField });
}
```

Docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: But that's only for initial state, I can't modify the value later on, as the constructor doesn't run again?

Comment: I updated my answer, you'll need a special lifecycle method

Answer (score 1):

Keep the onChange and value in the parent Component and pass it down as props:

```
class SimpleForm extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return (
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

class ParentOfForm extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            form_name: "",
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }
    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({form_name: e.target.value})
    }
    render()
    {
        return (
            <SimpleForm howDoIsendToInputField="garbage" 
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        value={this.state.form_name}/>


        )

    }
}
```